# VB.NET Decrypt a hash and show in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, encryption, hash, datagridview

My hash md5 + salt, Where in salt is pre-made inside the application.

```
Function md5hash(value As String) As Byte()
    Return md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value))
End Function

Function decrypt(encryptedString As String, key As String) As String
    de5.Key = md5hash(key)
    de5.Mode = CipherMode.ECB

    Dim buffer As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedString)

    Return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(de5.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))
End Function
```

Now I want to retrieve the data in the database that are hashed(encrypted). I can retrieve the data but in hashed. Not the equivalent string. Here is my DataGridView code.

```
 connection()
    Dim dataAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dataTable As New DataTable
    Dim bSource As New BindingSource

 Try
        conn.Open()

        Dim query As String
        query = "SELECT column07 AS 'Company ID', column08 AS Lastname, column12 AS Firstname, column06 AS Middlename, column02 AS 'Contact No.', column05 AS 'Current Address', column14 AS 'Permanent Address' FROM dbtest.table01 WHERE column15 = '" & encrypt("Single", salt) & "'"
        command = New MySqlCommand(query, conn) 'I think this is the part where I put my decrypt method.
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command     'Maybe here.
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable)             'I dont know where and how
        bSource.DataSource = dataTable          'Please help thanks!
        DataGridView_Accounts.DataSource = bSource
        dataAdapter.Update(dataTable)

        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Finally
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try
```

The query is working fine. Its just the decrypting(dehashing) is not.

Comment: Hashes are one way encryption, so they cant be decrypted.   Also, MD5 is a weal hash method by today's standards.

Comment: like i've said, retrieving is working. with the hashed data. it is even working in retrieving to a label/textbox. I just dont know how to retrieve it and show in datagridview.

Comment: We dont know what `de5` is and we cant see what `encrypt` does to understand much of what you are doing.  Going by the text and title, you cannot "dehash" a hash, thats the point of them.  I suspect you are encrypting and the MD5 is for hashing the salt?

Comment: its ok now, I run a loop. the decrypt function asked for a string not an array. So I have to retrieve them per row.

Answer (score 0):

```
connection()
Dim dataAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim dataTable As New DataTable
Dim bSource As New BindingSource

Try
    conn.Open()

    Dim query As String
    query = "SELECT column07 AS 'Company ID', column08 AS Lastname, column12 AS Firstname, column06 AS Middlename, column02 AS 'Contact No.', column05 AS 'Current Address', column14 AS 'Permanent Address' FROM dbtest.table01 WHERE column15 = '" & encrypt("Single", salt) & "'"
    command = New MySqlCommand(query, conn) 
    dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command 
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable)    
    bSource.DataSource = dataTable    
    DataGridView_Accounts.DataSource = bSource
    dataAdapter.Update(dataTable) '<===== remove this

    For i As Integer = 0 To dataTable.Rows.Count - 1
            dataTable.Rows(i)("Company ID") = decrypt(dataTable.Rows(i)("Company ID"), salt)
            'place all the columns here 1 by 1 =)
    Next

    conn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
Finally
    conn.Dispose()
End Try
```